# How to set cron_schedule and interval job with apscheduler

Tags: python

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import datetime
schedudler = Scheduler(daemonic = False)



@schedudler.cron_schedule(day_of_week='0-2', hour='9-10,13-15')
#@schedudler.interval_schedule(seconds=3)
def quote_send_sh_job():
    print 'a simple cron job start at: ', datetime.datetime.now()
    print "\n"

schedudler.start()
```

Using the code above, i can run shcedule task on Mon-Wed and hour '9-10,13-15'. But beside this condition, i aslo want this task to run every 3 seconds. So i set another interval_schedule. Then it works and print every 3 seconds, but the issue is that the first factor (day, hour) not work. So can you tell me how can implement both schedule and inverval task.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### a basic day, hour cron example:

```
>>> from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
>>> sc=Scheduler()
>>> sc.start()
>>> def quote_send_sh_job():
...  print 'a simple cron job'    
... 
>>> sc.add_cron_job(quote_send_sh_job,month='7',day='24',hour='10',minute=50)
```

#### for intervel based cron

```
>>> sc.add_interval_job(quote_send_sh_job, seconds=10)#every 10 seconds
```

[docs](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/intervalschedule.html)

Comment: TypeError: add_job() takes at least 5 arguments (4 given).  And can the two **add_cron_job** **add_job**  co-work?

Comment: @jim_wan2 [you can read this tutorial](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intervalschedule.html)

Comment: I only copy its sample code and still get this error **TypeError: add_job() takes at least 5 arguments (4 given)**, i install apscheduler by easy_install apscheduler. What's the problem?

Comment: @jim_wan2 oh i am really sorry it is 3.0.0 documentation. you are using 2.x.x version you can use `sc.add_interval_job(quote_send_sh_job, seconds=10)` , [doc](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/intervalschedule.html)